# Creating p-interesting graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, recreational-mathematics

> Let's call an undirected graph of n vertices p-interesting, if the following conditions fulfill:
> ?
> the graph contains exactly 2n + p edges;
> the graph doesn't contain self-loops and multiple edges;
> for any integer k (1 ≤ k ≤ n), any subgraph consisting of k vertices contains at most 2k + p edges.
>
> A subgraph of a graph is some set of the graph vertices and some set of the graph edges. At that, the set of edges must meet the condition: both ends of each edge from the set must belong to the chosen set of vertices.
>
> Your task is to find a p-interesting graph consisting of n vertices.

This a question from codeforces, https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/10972. However, I am finding the explanation impossible to understand. Does anyone understand why we are only considering 0 and 3-interesting subgraphs? To me, a triangle is a loop.

Comment: In the terminology of graph theory, a triangle is a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)). This is not the same as a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)).

Comment: That helps a bit, thanks @nickgard